# How does the FAA decide whether an aircraft is deemed a helicopter?

Tags: helicopter, aircraft-registration

This is a followup to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7984/2168).

How does the FAA decide whether a new aircraft will is deemed to be a helicopter for licencing and registration purposes?

Is there a law or regulation? Are there guidelines? Is there any case law where a manufacturer challenged a particular classification?

Answer (score 4):

The definition of a helicopter as well as other aircrafts is provided in **14 CFR Part 1**

http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=8403e178a4e1d0f8339151fe2529e600&node=14:1.0.1.1.1&rgn=div5

Manufacturers may seek clarification from the FAA about these definitions if/when there is a requirement .

Comment: So as long as a thing meets that definition, the FAA must licence it as a helicopter?

Comment: " Helicopter means a rotorcraft that, for its horizontal motion, depends principally on its engine-driven rotors." Seems pretty self-explanatory. Are you asking about airplanes such as the Osprey?

Comment: @RoboKaren Yeah it does seem self explanatory. Im just confirming that it actually is that simple.

Comment: YES ! The definition for a helicopter/rotorcraft is provided by the FAA . There is a Design Approval Process . Once approved a licence is issued http://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/design_approvals/rotorcraft/

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding... for example, the Volocopter will be deemed a helicopter by the FAA. Is that correct?

Comment: The Volocopter is basically a helicopter with more propellers than "conventional" helicopters .However,current FAA regulations do not yet address the specific design and airworthiness requirements of electric propulsion systems in aircraft. The F-37 Light Sport Aircraft Committee is currently carrying out a regulatory analysis of such systems(aircrafts).

Comment: @D_S is the V22 Osprey considered a rotorcraft or VTOL aircraft by the FAA?

Comment: @ RoboKaren  - FAA defines the Osprey as a TILTROTOR Aircraft . In other words it will be treated by FAA as a helicopter and not an aircraft .FAA's definition for a TILTROTOR aircraft is - " an aircraft which uses a pair or more of powered rotors (sometimes called proprotors) mounted on the rotating shaft or nacelles at the end of a fixed wing for lift and propulsion, and combines the vertical lift capability of a helicopter with the speed and range of a conventional fixed wing aircraft . " http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Notice/N_JO_7110.621.pdf

Comment: no, @D_S ,  check out "powered-lift" in 14 CFR 1: "Powered-lift means a heavier-than-air aircraft capable of vertical takeoff, vertical landing, and low speed flight that depends principally on engine-driven lift devices or engine thrust for lift during these flight regimes and on **nonrotating airfoil(s)** for lift during horizontal flight."